# NSPanel to secondary screen when in fullscreen mode

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

I am trying to get a NSPanel to fill a 2nd monitor when the main window goes into fullscreen mode.

I have the "Full Screen" setting on the panel to "Auxiliary Window" and it will stay on the screen I can drag it onto the other monitor manually and it is fine.  However, if I try to do it programmatically, it moves to another Space (although it is maximized on the correct screen).

```
-(void)windowDidEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Now in full screen");
    NSArray *screens = [NSScreen screens];

    for (NSScreen *screen in screens) {
        if ([self.window.screen isEqualTo:screen]) {
            NSLog(@"Main Window assigned to screen:%@",screen);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Assigning auxPanel to screen:%@",screen);
            NSRect screenRect = screen.frame;
            [self.auxPanel setFrame:screenRect display:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is interesting, is that if I enable the title bar (on the NSPanel) the above code works fine.  If I turn off the title bar on the panel, it moves to the other space.

Comment: Hello skwashua. Sorry to revert back with my own question here.
But, I would like to put my own question here which refers the same area. 
I am new and very much fresh with this functionality.
What I have to do is, I have a single window in my application. When user goes for a Full screen mode, I want to open up a new window in full screen, not the original single window which I have.
So, for that, what do I need to do here with Full Screen option having two options in it, Primary and auxiliary.
I will get that second window from object list. But, how to make this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the Title Bar needs to be enabled, but I just added:

```
[self.auxPanel setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```

and it seems to work well enough.